# how to implement onchange function in dynamically generated select tag

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

```
 var el_s = document.createElement('select');
      for(var i=1;i<32;i++)
      {
         var j = i;
          j = document.createElement('option');
          j.text=i;
          el_s.appendChild(j);
      }
table.appendChild(el_s);
```

i have to generate dynamically select tag and onchange method
how to implement onchange function in select tag so that i get the selected value from the dropdown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
el_s.onchange = function() {
    alert("jey");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/kyfnc/

Answer (score 1):

```
        var el_s = document.createElement('select');
      for(var i=1;i<32;i++)
      {
         var j = i;
          j = document.createElement('option');
          j.text=i;
          el_s.appendChild(j);
      }
    $(el_s).change(function(){
//your function code
alert("hi");
});
table.appendChild(el_s);
```